# symfony choice with ajax and database a simple solution for beginners

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

1- First you need to create a route:

```
Ajax Request handling:
  pattern:  /ajax/call1
  defaults: { _controller: MOBILEBIBundle:Web:ajax_call1 }
```

2- Create a function named: ajax_call1 inside your controller my case i have (Web):

```
public function ajax_call1Action(){
      $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
      $user = $request->request->get('user');

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getmanager();
      $all_users = $em->getRepository('MOBILEBIBundle:Service')->findByUser($user);
        $user_service = array();
        foreach($all_users as $single_user){
            $user_service[$single_user->getId()]=$single_user->getDescription();

        }

      $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true, "user_service"=>$user_service);
      return new Response(json_encode($response)); 
}
```

3- In your twig file make a jquery function that will send ajax request on change drop down

```
        $(function(){
          $(".select-user").change(function(){
          $userval = $(".select-user").val();

            $.post('{{path('Ajax Request handling')}}',               
               {user: $userval},
                function(response){
                    if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
                       $('.select-parent').find('option').remove();  
                       $.each(response.user_service, function(key, value) {   
                             $('.select-parent')
                                 .append($("<option></option>")
                                 .attr("value",key)
                                 .text(value)); 
                        });
                    }

                }, "json");    
          });
        });
```

4- Two drop downs:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select User: </label>
                                        <br/>
                                        {{ form_widget(form.user, {'attr':{'class':'select-user form-control'}}) }}
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Select Parant Service: </label>
                                        <br/>
                                             {{ form_widget(form.parent, {'attr':{'id':'selectparent', 'class':'select-parent form-control'}}) }}

                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: More importantly:  What the heck is a parant?